# Why aren't the degrees of freedom included in the confidence interval formula?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, statistical-inference

I have one question.  In the formula for calculating the confidence interval, I don't see the degrees of freedom in the formula.

In my book, the formula is : 
$$\text{Confidence interval:} \qquad \mu = \bar{x} \pm t_{\alpha/2} \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Why it's not this instead ?
$$\text{Confidence interval:} \qquad \mu = \bar{x} \pm t_{\alpha/2,n-1} \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I would say that this is a matter of style or convenience (or both!).

I think the author(s) of you book felt that the degrees of freedom should be "clear from context" and didn't feel like including it in the formula, possibly for typographical convenience.

I pulled up some notes I have and it looks like the author chose to ***include*** what you pointed out, except in a different style,

$$\hat \beta\pm t_{n-2}(1-\alpha/2)s_{\hat\beta_i}.$$

The formula is not calculating the same thing as yours, but  as you can see, it is possible to include the degrees of freedom in the notation.